# Como sortear números aleatórios repetidamente de modo que não seja sorteado o mesmo número?

Tags: python

```py
from random import randint

# Dados
lista_tentativas = list()
quantidade_tentativas  = 0

# Entrada de dados
x = int(input('Informe um numero entre 0 e 10:'))

# Tentativas
while True:
    y = randint(0,10)
    quantidade_tentativas += 1
    lista_tentativas.append(y)
    if y == x:
        print('O numero digitado foi {}')
        print(f'Essas foram todas as minhas tentativas: {lista_tentativas}')
        print(f'Essa foi a quantidade total de tentativas: {quantidade_tentativas} tentativas')
        break
```

Da forma que estou fazendo existe a possibilidade de tentativa do mesmo número. Quero remover essa possibilidade. Mas como?

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se o número digitado está na lista de tentativas. Se estiver, peça/sorteie outro número, antes de incrementar a quantidade de tentativas:

```
while True:
    y = randint(0,10)
    if y in lista_tentativas:
        continue # ja existe, tenta outro numero
    quantidade_tentativas += 1
    lista_tentativas.append(y)
    if y == x:
        print('O numero digitado foi {}')
        print(f'Essas foram todas as minhas tentativas: {lista_tentativas}')
        print(f'Essa foi a quantidade total de tentativas: {quantidade_tentativas} tentativas')
        break
```

Comment: Como sua resposta já contempla o que o AP pede, eu apenas vou deixar a dica de que `lista_tentativas` seja um `set()` pois é uma estrutura de dados otimizada para casos como este. ;D

Comment: @fernandosavio concordo, mas estou achando mais didático deixar o código da resposta o mais parecido possível com o da pergunta, para facilitar o entendimento

Comment: Não foi uma sugestão de mudança, a resposta está boa. Deixei o comentário para que as pessoas leiam depois de ler sua resposta, como um complemento. :)